# Bind function to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascript which generates some html elements, like below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < suggestions.length; i++) {
                    var suggestion = suggestions[i];

                    var $li = $('<li data-profile-id="'+ suggestion.id + '" data-profile-name="'+suggestion.first_name + ' ' + suggestion.last_name + ' " class="search-name-result" ></li>');
                    $suggestionsUl.append($li);

                    var $img = $('<img src="/img/profile/' + suggestion.picture_url + '" class="search-suggest-img pull-left" />');
                    $li.append($img);

                    var $link = $('<a href="' + suggestion.id + '">' + suggestion.first_name + ' ' + suggestion.last_name + '</a>');
                    $li.append($link);
                }
```

What I need to be able to do is also assign a function to each dynamically created li element, something like the below code:

```
$('.search-name-result').on('click', function(e){
            $input.val($('.search-name-result').data('profile-name'));
        });
```

But im not sure how to assign this to each li when they are created.

Thanks

Comment: atleast do a search with the title itself before posting the question...

Comment: We get this question like twice a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, but actually **delegate** it using a parent container like `document`

```
$(document).on('click','.search-name-result', function(e){
            $input.val($(this).data('profile-name'));
        });
```

Also, you can change

`$('.search-name-result').data('profile-name'))`

to use `$(this)` like

```
$(this).data('profile-name'))
```

since it will be the clicked `.search-name-result`

Comment: @Bala, didnt notice that. Good point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use *event delegation* for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click','.search-name-result', function(e){
        $input.val($('.search-name-result').data('profile-name'));
});
```